# how to assign Strong Name to an Assembly?

Tags: assemblies, strongname, gacutil

I have created strong name using -

```
sn -k C:\strong.snk
```

nao how to assign this key to any assembly? and where I have to use `gacutil`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going on the assumption of a .NET Framework project in Visual Studio.

- Project Menu
- [Project Name] Properties
- Signing
- Check "Sign the assembly"
- Click the "Choose a strong name key file:" drop down then click ""
- Find your key and select!
- ...?
- Profit!